# Abrir llaves de PHP en Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio

Posiblemente la pregunta sea un poco "chunga", pero no doy con la combinación para abrir las llaves de PHP

```
<?php ?>
```

como en Sublimetext tecleando php + TAB ya sea en un archivo con extension php o html. Ahora al teclear php y darle a TAB me añade las etiquetas de HTML

```
 <php></php>
```

Tengo instalado en VStudio Code Emmet y PhpIntellisense.

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 3):

Ve a `Preferences/User Snippets`, selecciona la opción html y agrega el siguiente snippet:

```
    "php": {
        "prefix": "php",
        "body": [
            "<?php",
            "$1",
            "?>"
        ],
        "description": "php tag"
    }
```

Y asegurate de que en la opción "Select Language Mode" en la status bar de visual studio code esté seleccionado PHP o HTML si el archivo es nuevo.

Comment: Gracias. Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias. No encontraba ninguna solucion a esto.